# Can't receive image properly from an API through Flutter

Tags: python, flutter, image, api, post

I am running an API in python. The API have a POST request that receives the image, process it and sends a processed image in response. I have successfully sent the image to the API in Flutter but after sending, the response is raising an `Error: XMLHttpRequest error` but the API logs success in the cmd `127.0.0.1 - - [09/May/2023 22:53:27] "POST /predict HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

I don't know where the error is occurring, whether in API code or in Flutter code. Someone please help.

Flutter:

```
Future<Image?> _predict() async {
  final url = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/predict');
  final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);
  request.fields['type'] = 'png';

  final imagePath = "C:/Users/Cheems/Pictures/Screenshots/pred.png";
  final imageFile = File(imagePath);
  request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', imageFile.path));

  final response = await request.send(); # error is raising in this line itself (Error: XMLHttpRequest error)
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final responseBytes = await response.stream.toBytes();
    return Image.memory(responseBytes);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Python API code:

```
import os
import shutil
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import json
from io import BytesIO
import cgi
from yolov5 import detect


class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_cors_headers(self):
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")

    def do_OPTIONS(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self._set_cors_headers()
        self.end_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        if self.path == '/predict':
            try:
                shutil.rmtree('./yolov5/runs')
            except:
                pass
            try:
                shutil.rmtree('./yolov5/data/images')
                os.mkdir("./yolov5/data/images")
            except:
                pass

            content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
            content_type = self.headers['Content-Type']

            request_body = self.rfile.read(content_length)
            request_io = BytesIO(request_body)

            form_data = cgi.FieldStorage(
                fp=request_io,
                headers=self.headers,
                environ={
                    'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',
                    'CONTENT_TYPE': content_type,
                }
            )

            json_data = json.loads(form_data.getvalue('data'))

            image_type = json_data['type']

            image_part = form_data.getfirst('image')

            if image_part:
                filename = f"image.{image_type}"
                save_path = f'./yolov5/data/images/{filename}'
                with open(save_path, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(image_part)

                detect.main()

                image_path = f'./yolov5/runs/detect/exp/{filename}'

                with open(image_path, 'rb') as f:
                    image_data = f.read()

                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'image/jpeg')
                self.send_header('Content-disposition',
                                 f'attachment; filename="{filename}"')
                self.wfile.write(image_data)
                self._set_cors_headers()
                self.end_headers()

            else:
                self.send_response(404)
                self.end_headers()

        else:
            self.send_response(404)
            self.end_headers()


def run_server():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 8000
    server_address = (host, port)

    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, RequestHandler)
    httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_server()
```